# In EAR project EJBs appear twice when deployng

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, ejb, websphere

When I deploy EAR project, I noted that same EJBs appear twice - in WAR and JAR(EJB) modules. Where can be problem?

[image]
[image]

I build project using Maven. And didn't explicitly define any `ejb-jar.xml`.

In `pom.xml` of EJB project I added `maven-ejb-plugin`:

```
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
            <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
            <archive>
                <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
            </archive>
            <generateClient>true</generateClient>
            <clientExcludes>
                <clientExclude>**/core/</clientExclude>
                <clientExclude>**/utils/</clientExclude>
            </clientExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

And from client I refer to generated EJB-client:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>orgstructure</groupId>
            <artifactId>orgstructure-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>ejb-client</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

P.S. I deploy project to WebSphere 8.

**UPDATE**

Generated `.ear` file have standard layout:

```
-project.ear
   --web-module.war
   --ejb-module.jar
   --lib
   --META-INF
```

And generated `applcation.xml`:

```
 <display-name>orgstructure-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>orgstructure-web-1.0.3.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/orgstructure</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>orgstructure-ejb-1.0.3.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
```

Comment: Could you also provide content of the ear maven builds and the content of the application.xml in the ear file. Thx.

Comment: Are the EJB-classes in the war-archieve under WEB-INF\classes or in an jar-archieve unter WEB-INF\lib? Did maven generate the 2 ejb-jar.xml´s??

Comment: @mszalbach updated question. Please review.

Comment: @cljk No, EJB classes located under `ejb-module.jar/package1/package2/...`. And maven didn't generated any `ejb-jar.xml` at all, i.e. my `.ear` doesn't contain `ejb-jar.xml` (I think because since EJB 3 `ejb-jar.xml` is optional). Under `web-module.war/WEB-INF/lib` I have only ejb-client.jar classes

Comment: Thx. So it looks correct your ear has the war and the ejb-jar as dependency so both are deployed. Now maybe add the content of the war, ejb-jar file and there poms. Maybe there is something wrong with transitive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Are you building (except for the EJB and web modules) a standalone Java application that is going to use your EJB? I'm guessing not, since you don't mention it anywhere.

If I'm guessing right, don't generate the EJB client. Remove the option

```
<generateClient>true</generateClient>
```

from your POM, and all configuration related to it.

An **EJB client** in this context means an application deployed **outside** the application server that wants to use your EJBs directly and therefore it needs a client jar to handle remote calls to the beans on the server.

If I'm guessing wrong, you still should not include a dependency to your a client jar in your web archive, Java EE web applications connect to EJBs using built-in app server mechanisms, not generated client stubs. In that case, remove the option

```
<type>ejb-client</type>
```

from your WAR's dependency.